# How to remove time part from DateTime variable in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

In my view I have a date field (which used for Jquery Date Picker),

```
@if (Model != null)
{
  if (Model.SubmitStartDate == DateTime.MinValue)
  {
    Model.SubmitStartDate = null;
  }                    
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubmitStartDate , new { @Id = "SubmitStartDate", @readonly = "readonly", @Value = @Model.SubmitStartDate})
}
```

In my Model I have :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a start date")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime? SubmitStartDate { get; set; }
```

However in UI I get **10/07/2013 00:00:00** on load , How can I remove the time part from this. Also I require date in the format **"dd-mm-yy"**. Is it possible to achieve?

**UPDATE**

I edited my code as per the answers, and I got it worked as per requirement, however I got a problem.

When I use `@Html.EditorFor()` my `readonly` property will not work any more. I tried with `DisplayFor` too, however it doesn't make sense as I was using it for a J-query **Date Picker**. Is there any way I can make that field to read only?

updated Code:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
  if (Model.SubmitStartDate == DateTime.MinValue)
  {
    Model.SubmitStartDate = null;
  }                    
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubmitStartDate , new { type = "date", @Id = "SubmitStartDate", @readonly = "readonly", @Value = @Model.SubmitStartDate})
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using a `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helper which will ignore your `DisplayFormat` attribute. Change it to a `@Html.EditorFor()` and your DisplayFormat will be applied.

And to get your format:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yy}")]
public DateTime? SubmitStartDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: And change the DataFormatString to "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"

Comment: Just for completeness' sake: if you only need to remove the time part (I know, this is not your only requirement), add the attribute `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ya actually it work like charm :) however my read-only property is not working anymore, when I use Editfor `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubmitStartDate , new {type = "date", @Id = "SubmitStartDate ", @readonly = "readonly", @Value = @Model.SubmitStartDate })`

Comment: @TBA, use `@Html.DisplayFor()` if it's a readonly property. Also, another advantage of using `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor` is that you can implement custom templates for a model (i.e. what HTML and edit field for your model should render).

Comment: Hi Anton, I updated my question, I was using the said field for a `Jquery datepicker`, if I use an `@Html.DisplayFor()`, I can't use that with my `DatePicker`.

Comment: @TBA, if it's a datepicker..then why is it a readonly? Sorry, I'm not following.

Comment: Well the user should only select from the calender, and the selected value should not be editable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I normally format data annotation in order to work in both chrome and IE.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartDate, new { type = "date" })
```